# TabControl - Loading Default UI Elements in New Tab

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a TabControl in my application but I want to allow the user to create a new tab, but when the new tab is created it contains some default form controls. All new tabs created will contain the same basic form controls per tab (think NotePad++ where each new tab has a text editor within it).

Is there some sort of design pattern or template I can use so that when a new tab is created it will contain the necessary form controls required by my application?

Just to convey some meaning a little more:

1. User clicks "New Tab"
2. New tab is loaded with a text editor and a tree view
3. User clicks "New Tab" again
4. New tab is loaded with a text editor and a tree view

... and the processes repeats for any number of tabs that the user requires.

Comment: Yes, a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx).

Comment: Was about to say exactly this.... investigate creating a user control and then load that into each tab as it's required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments suggest you should create a `UserControl`, lets say you call it `TextEditorControl`. Then you can add tab pages on a button click using the following method

```
private void AddTabPage()
{
    // Add new tab page and dock fill.
    TabPage tab = new TabPage(Path.GetFileName(fullPath));
    TextEditorControl editor = new TextEditorControl();
    editor.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

    // Add the new tab to the tab control.
    tab.Controls.Add(editor);
    fileTabs.Controls.Add(tab);
    fileTabs.SelectedTab = tab;
}
```

I hope this helps.